# concatenate 2 items in list in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have a list and I a trying to concatenate 2 items in the list using `.join()`.

Sample data:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
str = ' '.join(l[1:2])
print(str)
```

The output prints only `b` but I am expecting to print `b c`. someone point me what is wrong here

Comment: `l[1:2]` starts at index 1 but end _before_ index 2, so it only has 1 item in it, `'b'`. So you want `' '.join(l[1:3])`

Comment: indexing goes `[start:exclusive end]`, if you index `[1:2]` you are going from `1` to `2` exclusive, so just the element at index `1`, which is b

Comment: BTW, don't use `str` as a variable name: that shadows the built-in `str` type, which can lead to mysterious error messages if you later try to do stuff like `str(42)`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I was searching for concatenation in list and the duplicate question which U have mentioned dint come up in my search results.It is not like I am vaguely asking someone to explain a concept. I tried an method and it dint workout so asking for help.

Comment: That's ok. It can be hard to find the right question when you don't understand what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
string = ' '.join(l[1:3])
print(string)
```

Your index is ending before 2, using `[1:3]` includes 2.  You also had some syntax error in your list for `c` and `d`

EDIT: as others have stated I'd also recommend avoiding "str" use since str() is used in python to convert into a string.

Comment: `str` isn't a function, it's a class (also known as a type). Yes, you can call it, but that doesn't make it a function.

Answer (score 1):

from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html), slicing of list as `l[a:b]` `a` is inclusive but `b` is exclusive, hence the desired results